# Bus error (core dumped). 0%

Tags: updates, hard-drive

If I run `sudo apt-get update`
or `sudo apt-get upgrade` etc.
I get **Bus error (core dumped). 0%**

In logs I can see:

```
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.366988] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367023] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367036] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367056] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:c8:f0:97:eb/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 4096 in
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367056]          res 41/40:00:f7:97:eb/00:00:12:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367067] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367073] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368527] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368567] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368577] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368585] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368595] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 12 eb 97 f0 00 00 08 00
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368600] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 317429751
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.368679] ata1: EH complete
----
```

(I wonder why is an media error?)
After executing

```
hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --repair-sector 317429751 /dev/sda
```

I get next sector error, in this case 317429752.
I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Disks1:

[image: Disks1]

Disks2:

[image: Disks2]

Comment: I would check the health of your device sda (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  ie. hardware issue

Comment: Hi, yes I will run long test, I release it is a problem with external HDD although I have no Externlal HDD conected :(

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi heynema, thanks for repying, I will let you know in few days, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have NCQ errors.**

```
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367036] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367056] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:c8:f0:97:eb/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 4096 in
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367056]          res 41/40:00:f7:97:eb/00:00:12:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367067] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 27 12:49:22 topic1 kernel: [37586.367073] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

**First we `fsck`...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then we patch NCQ...**

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**Then we bad block...**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #1:**

After reviewing the SMART Data, it looks like your HDD is toast. If you look at image #1, overall assessment, you'll see it says **2840 bad sectors**. That's not good. Also the **read error rate** and the **relocated sector count** and **current pending sector count** are all real bad.

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and backup whatever files you can to an external HDD, and then replace the drive.

Comment: Hello, I had 0.7% of non-contiguous files, I am on 6% od e2fsck at the moment

Comment: @NenadJaksic Good job! Now just be patient and let the bad blocking continue to its end. Report back.

Comment: I have now  Segmetation error (core dumped).

Comment: Looks like it replaced some segments but not solved still.

Comment: @NenadJaksic Did you do the NCQ patch? How did the bad blocking go? Did it find any bad blocks? Start the `Disks` application, and edit your question with screenshots of the SMART Data scrollable window.

Comment: I did NCQ patch, I can try e2fsck once again, it was over 6 hours and I had about 1300 errors, to me looked like all solved, but now I have Segmentatin instead of Bus error

Comment: I believe it is a problem? I can not scan direct /dev/sda (it says it is busy) instead I can e2fsck only on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root device

Comment: @NenadJaksic 1300 errors? Oh oh. Start the `Disks` app, and take screenshots of the SMART Data scrollable window, and edit them into your question.

Comment: Sorry I can not figure how I can add here screenshoot

Comment: @NenadJaksic Edit your question. Click on the small icon with the "mountain range" on it. Add your screenshots as a paste or browse, or if you've already loaded the screenshots at imgur.com, you can give it the URLs.

Comment: Yes, just addes above 2 images

Comment: Sorry how you know that HDD is toasted?

Comment: @NenadJaksic Fair question. If you look at image #1, overall assessment, you'll see it says **2840 bad sectors**. That's not good. Also the **read error rate** and the **relocated sector count** and **current pending sector count** are all real bad.